Angular velocity basics
Is angular velocity only defined for circular motion or can it be described for lets say projectile motion as well?

It will be a rather uselessly varying thing, which is why it is rarely considered in textbooks on the topic. But it should be well-defined and perfectly workable. What have you tried?

You should also probably specify whether you're considering projectiles that go far enough horizontally to make the curvature of the earth significant, or not

Angular velocity can be defined for any trajectory about any fixed point - it is simply the rate of change of the angle between the line of sight from the fixed point to the projectile and some (arbitrary) fixed base line. Whether it is a useful attribute that helps us analyse and understand the trajectory is a separate question.

@gandalf61 , Can you provide more context and explain with an example ?

@PrithuBharadwaj I will if the question is reopened.

@PrithuBharadwaj The definition of angular velocity in 2D is simply the rate of change of the polar angle. So you just have to convert the position into polar coordinates and evaluate $\mathrm{d}\theta/\mathrm{d}t$.

@PrithuBharadwaj "What is the angular velocity of a pt particle about the point of projection, during a projectile motion?" This site is not a place to ask for specific computations to be done for you but rather a place to ask about conceptual difficulties. If you can show what you've tried and where you're stuck (or just removing your first question since your second question is fine), I will consider voting to reopen.

@VincentThacker I had a general doubt about angular velocity , and not a specific doubt about projectile motion. If you say so I'll delete the first part of question?

@PrithuBharadwaj Yes, and also make your doubt clearer.

Please vote to reopen the question

@PrithuBharadwaj In the edit page, you need to check the box to submit for review. Then others will be able to review and reopen it.

@gandalf61 , can you answer now?

@PrithuBharadwaj Others have posted great answers below. I don't think there is anything I can add to their answers.

For any two-dimensional motion we can switch to polar coordinates:
$$
x,y\rightarrow r,\phi,\\
x=r\cos\phi, y=r\sin\phi.
$$
Then instead of linear velocities $v_x=\dot{x},v_y=\dot{y}$ we will have radial and angular velocities:
$$
v_r=\dot{r}, \omega=\dot{\phi}.
$$
Similar approach is possible in in spherical coordinates, but, since in that case we have two angles characterizing position, term angular velocity becomes ambiguous. It is thus customary to speak about the velocity of rotation about a selected axis, whose direction is specified in three dimensions.

Absolutely, the angular momentum of a particle or object is defined regardless of the shape of its trajectory. The angular momentum of a particle is simply $\vec{r} \times \vec{p}$, where $\vec{r}$ is its position vector and $\vec{p}$ is its momentum vector.
If you are reasoning about the angular momentum of a particle which is moving in a circular orbit, then it would be natural to define the origin of your coordinate system at the center of that orbit. But all the laws of mechanics which concern angular momentum remain true no matter where the origin is.

This is a good question because angular velocity for a particle in circular motion only makes sense if you consider a virtual rigid body with zero mass, except for this one particle and you track this particle's velocity as it moves around in space but he body is pinned to the origin.

In the context of a particle being part of a rigid body you can write the famous equation for the velocity vector $\vec{v}$ in terms of the position $\vec{r}$ and a constant vector $\vec{\omega}$ which we call angular velocity:
$$ \vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r} \tag{1}$$
This angular velocity vector designates this axis of rotation, at least in terms of its magnitude and direction.
Many textbooks call this virtual rigid body a rotating frame. It is the same thing as the parts of the rotating frame move together, just as the parts of a rigid body move together is it moves trough space.
Now for your question, as I understand it. What if the path of the particle isn't a circle, and its distance from the origin isn't fixed, and hence cannot be considered part of a rigid body that is pinned to the origin?

There is the school of thought that at any instant you can recover some angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$ from the velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$ and the position $\vec{r}$ with
$$ \vec{\omega}_{\perp} = \frac{\vec{r}\times\vec{v}}{\|\vec{r}\|^{2}} \tag{2}$$
but this only recovers the components of $\vec{\omega}$ that are perpendicular to $\vec{r}$.
Some say that you can always attach a rigid body to a moving particle, but this body cannot be pinned to the ground. The most general case happens when at any instant this rigid body is rotating about some arbitrary point and having a parallel velocity  $\vec{v}_\parallel$ along the axis of rotation such that the velocity of the particle is decomposed as:
$$ \vec{v} = \vec{v}_\parallel + \vec{\omega}\times \vec{r} \tag{3} $$
with the location of the axis of rotation found by
$$ \vec{r} = \frac{ \vec{v} \times \vec{\omega} }{\| \vec{\omega} \|^2} \tag{4}$$ or at least the point on this axis of rotation closest to the origin.
With this view, the rotational velocity $\vec{\omega}$ is a well-defined quantity that arises from the requirement that all particles within a rigid body must maintain fixed distances with each other. This leads to the transformation law for velocities between two points A and B as
$$ \vec{v}_A = \vec{v}_B + \vec{\omega} \times (\vec{r}_A - \vec{r}_B)  \tag{5}$$
